# How to wire 2" recessed LED Downlights with inline AC to DC LED driver

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, low-voltage

I recently purchased a four-pack of 2" recessed led accent downlights to install in a gyp board ceiling.  The lights arrived and have a 6" cord from them which connects to a LED driver.  A bundle of two wires exit the driver which look to be 16 or 18-gauge wires each.  The directions indicate these are to connect to a 110V power source. My understanding of the NEC residential electrical code is the wires from the driver are too small and they also need to connect to 110V AC power in a junction box.  Neither of these are possible in this case without demolishing the ceiling. Their installation video shows each LED driver connecting to an unbundled 110V Positive and neutral wire, but this has to be a code violation. My assumption is I need to remove the drivers and splice wire extensions from the lights into the adjacent furnace room where I can connect them to a remote driver.  In this way all the lights pulled through the soffit would be low voltage and could then connect to a remote driver.  I was thinking I could buy a single driver to connect them to instead of four small remote drivers.  Is this on the right track?  If so can buy a driver such as this to directly connect my 110V power to without it being in a junction box?  Also what size does it need to be to power 4 dimmable LED lights rated at 5W? FYI - Each light came wired to a LED Driver with an input listed as AC90-265V 50/60Hz and an output current of DC 12V 550mA.

Comment: Is this product listed by UL or ETL? If not, back it goes.

Comment: "If so can buy a driver such as this to directly connect my 110V power to without it being in a junction box?" Only if the driver is plug in. Otherwise any wire junction _must_ be in a junction box. Hence the name. It's not just there to annoy you, but to slow/stop fires from a miswired or poorly designed product.

Comment: Also, as written, this question is far too broad. If you'll take the [tour] and read up on [how to ask a question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), you'll note that we work on a "one question per post" basis here, unlike general discussion boards.

Comment: You likely need a driver per light, dumb pucks are typically constant current, not constant voltage, and a driver can't give the right amount of current to a single lamp in a chain since they would all have the same current, regardless of temp and defects. They do make nice options these days that have a code-friendly metal box on each driver/lamp combo, i got a 6 pack for about $50 on amazon (UL listed).

Answer (score 2):

Code actually permits listed devices to use smaller wires than the circuits supplying them do (18AWG in light fixtures is common, even though 14 AWG is the minimum in the circuit leading to them) but that depends on the device passing Nationally Recognized Testing Laboratory tests in that configuration.

And if it's not tested by a NRTL, it's illegal (a code violation) to install it no matter what size the wires are. Of course, you also seem to need a bit more self-education if you think there's such a thing as

> 110V Positive and neutral wire

In the US or Canada. The supply is ALTERNATING current, and has been 120VAC nominal for at least 50 years. Referring to "positive" in that context suggests a real need to hit the books before you do more wiring.

As for the connection to other wires, that's normally managed in a junction box, which can be accessible through the hole in the ceiling.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating 5W times 4 lights at 12V gives a current of 1.67A.  So I would go for a 2A minimum, 12V output.  You will have to select a cable to cope with that.

With an alternative power supply, they may no longer be dimmable.